# .outerHeight & .outerWidth grows exponentially, when setting table cell height & width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

- Another web developer wanted to freeze the left-most column and allow scrolling of the table. He found this code and implemented into his client's site.  The code does its job and works as expected.
- However he added some @media queries to make the table a bit more responsive. When doing so it screwed up the table. It left the left column to not be aligned with the rest of the table.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  .exportTable th{
    min-width: 170px !important;
  }
  .exportTable td{
    min-width:170px !important;
    max-width:170px !important;
  }
}
```

So I added the function call inside a window.resize().

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  app_handle_listing_horisontal_scroll($('#exportTable-listing'));
  app_handle_listing_horisontal_scroll($('#exportTable-listing2'));
  $(window).resize(function() {
    app_handle_listing_horisontal_scroll($('#exportTable-listing'));
    app_handle_listing_horisontal_scroll($('#exportTable-listing2'));
  });
});
```

- The code was called upon resize of the window however, the outerHeight and outerWidth grew exponentially, causing a serious issue.

The issue happens when you set the height:

```js
$(this).css('height', current_row_height);
```

and the width/margin:

```js
$(this).css('position','absolute')
              .css('margin-left','-'+table_collumns_margin[index]+'px')
              .css('width',table_collumns_width[index])
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzu0ojac/10/).

Simply grab the window and resize back and forth, the table cell's height/width will exponentially grow, causing a serious issue.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzu0ojac/11/) demonstrates how when you hit the @media queries that the left column will be misaligned. (it's important when viewing this fiddle to get the @media query to be hit.)

How can I resolve these issues?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  To prevent it from resizing the columns, just remove your code from `$(window).resize(function(){}`

Comment: The code is designed to freeze the left column, it does this by setting width and heights of that left column to match the rest of the table. The code does exactly as expected however, in conjuction with at media queries those value no longer make the table look good. So the code needs to be rerun, a refresh of the page would accomplish the goal. However a refresh on window resize is bad practice. So I put the code into the resize so that the code will readjust the height and width of the left column to match the table, the undesired effect is that those height and width value will grow.

Comment: Take the js code out of the resize the problem of exponential growth will be fixed.  However when the at media queries are hit the left column no longer matches the table. Refreshing the page which reloads the js fixes it.  So we need to have the code run in the resize to make the table responsive with the js.

Comment: So is this not the desired effect?  https://jsfiddle.net/zzu0ojac/11/  The left column is frozen and the page still resizes without issue.

Comment: No, once the @media Queries are hit the left column doesnt align properly with the rest of the table. The code NEEDS to be run on window resize. I said all of this inside my question...

Comment: You need to reset column width and height to `auto` before you measure outerWidth and outerHeight.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, adding javascript to the equation makes it overly complex.  I believe what you want can be accomplished with CSS alone.

How this works, if the browser has a max-width of 500px, then remove the sticky column.  If not, show the sticky column.

Unless you need to support browsers older than IE 9, then try this on for size:

https://jsfiddle.net/BmLpV/284/

CSS:

```
.zui-table {
    border: none;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: none;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zui-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.zui-scroller {
    margin-left: 141px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
.zui-table .zui-sticky-col {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 120px;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .zui-table .zui-sticky-col {
      border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
      border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
      position: relative;
      top: auto;
      width: auto;
  }
  .zui-scroller {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="zui-wrapper">
    <div class="zui-scroller">
        <table class="zui-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="zui-sticky-col">Name</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Height</th>
                    <th>Born</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Prior to NBA/Country</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">DeMarcus Cousins</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>6'11"</td>
                    <td>08-13-1990</td>
                    <td>$4,917,000</td>
                    <td>Kentucky/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Isaiah Thomas</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>PG</td>
                    <td>5'9"</td>
                    <td>02-07-1989</td>
                    <td>$473,604</td>
                    <td>Washington/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Ben McLemore</td>
                    <td>16</td>
                    <td>SG</td>
                    <td>6'5"</td>
                    <td>02-11-1993</td>
                    <td>$2,895,960</td>
                    <td>Kansas/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Marcus Thornton</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>SG</td>
                    <td>6'4"</td>
                    <td>05-05-1987</td>
                    <td>$7,000,000</td>
                    <td>Louisiana State/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Jason Thompson</td>
                    <td>34</td>
                    <td>PF</td>
                    <td>6'11"</td>
                    <td>06-21-1986</td>
                    <td>$3,001,000</td>
                    <td>Rider/USA</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** To support dynamic heights, you could do something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.zui-table tr').each(function(i, row) {
    var height = $('.zui-sticky-col').eq(i).outerHeight() - $('.zui-sticky-col').eq(i).height();
    $('.zui-sticky-col').eq(i).height($(row).height() - height);
  });
})
```

For better performance, you could only access the element once:

```
$(function(){
  $('.zui-table tr').each(function(i, row) {
    var el = $('.zui-sticky-col').eq(i);
    var height = el.outerHeight() - el.height();
    el.height($(row).height() - height);
  });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BmLpV/289/

Comment: Unfortunately, When you have a larger Cell, the rest of the row is misalligned:
https://jsfiddle.net/BmLpV/285/

This is why The Developer was using JS.

Comment: After some time I managed to incorporate this code into the website.  I like this solution.  However ultimately I would like to know why they original code had the issues that it did.  If you could give me a little info as to what was going on.  I can mark the question answered.  Ty for all your help.

Comment: Honestly, I may not have time to assess why the old code didn't work.  As you can see, the old approach to solving the problem was quite long-winded.  If I get time I will try to peer into it and comment back.  Thanks for understanding.